# stubs and mocks in R

Tags: r, testing

I've spent lots of time with RSpec and some time with xunit style tests. I've gotten accustom to having mocks and stubbing at my disposal.

Is there anything like mocks or stubbing in R? What frameworks have them?

If not how do you isolate your tests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It wasn't available until 4 years after you asked this question, but it looks like `testthat` does include a `with_mock()` function now:

https://github.com/hadley/testthat/blob/master/R/mock.R

Seems to fit the bill pretty well.

Comment: `with_mock()` is now deprecated

Answer (score 4):

There are the CRAN packages [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RUnit), [svUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=svUnit) and [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/package=testthat) all of which provide unit testing for R.

If you need a different framework you may have to write it.  CRAN will gladly accept your code (if it meets the usual standards).

Answer (score 4):

There is also the `stub` function in the [mockery](https://github.com/n-s-f/mockery) package. It is similar to `with_mock`, but also allows for stubbing out primitives and functions from base R packages.

Example:

```
g = function(y) y
f = function(x) g(x) + 1
test_that('demonstrate stubbing', {
    # before stubbing
    expect_equal(f(1), 2)

    # replace the function 'g' when called from 'f'
    stub(f, 'g', function(...) 100)
    expect_equal(f(1), 101)
})
```